# XML declaration parsing failed error on executing java client.This program is trying to connect online php soap server

Tags: java, php, xml, soap

I am using a java program as client and a a php server located at Ip.
I tried to connect from client but it is showing following error.

```
error:Aug 06, 2015 6:13:16 PM com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl lookForXmlDecl

SEVERE: SAAJ0552: XML declaration parsing failed
```

Code:

```
  package javaapplication1;

/*!
 * java soap client - php soap server

 */


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.MimeHeaders;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPPart;

import org.w3c.dom.Node;


public class soapclient {

  public static void main(String [] args) {

      String operation = "get_names";
      String urn = "framework";
      String destination = "http://erumely.orgfree.com/server.php";

      try
      {
          // First create the connection
          SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
          SOAPConnection connection = soapConnFactory.createConnection();

          // Next, create the actual message
          MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
          SOAPMessage message = messageFactory.createMessage();

          SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart();
          SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();

          // set username and password into header for basic authentication
          String authorization = Base64Coder.encodeString("123:123");
          MimeHeaders hd = message.getMimeHeaders();
          hd.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authorization);

      // Create and populate the body
      SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();

      // Create the main element and namespace
      SOAPElement bodyElement = body.addChildElement(envelope.createName(operation, "ns1", "urn:"+urn));

      bodyElement.addChildElement("in0").addTextNode("alexander");


      // Save the message
      message.saveChanges();


      // Send the message and get the reply
      SOAPMessage reply = connection.call(message, destination);

      // Retrieve the result - no error checking is done: BAD!
      soapPart = reply.getSOAPPart();
      envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
      body = envelope.getBody();

      Node returnvalue = (Node) body.getChildElements().next();

      if (returnvalue != null) { 
          if (returnvalue.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeName().equals("return")) {

          List<HashMap<String,String>> ReturnArray = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
          // we have some values, trying to read them now
          for (int i=0;i<returnvalue.getChildNodes().item(0).getChildNodes().getLength();i++) {
              if (returnvalue.getChildNodes().item(0).getChildNodes().item(i).getNodeName().equals("item")) {
                  HashMap<String,String> keyvaluepairs = new HashMap<String,String> ();
                  for (int j=0;j<returnvalue.getChildNodes().item(0).getChildNodes().item(i).getChildNodes().getLength();j++){
                      System.out.print("("+returnvalue.getChildNodes().item(0).getChildNodes().item(i).getChildNodes().getLength()+"/"+j+")");
                      String key=returnvalue.getChildNodes().item(0).getChildNodes().item(i).getChildNodes().item(j).getNodeName();
                      String value;
                      if (returnvalue.getChildNodes().item(0).getChildNodes().item(i).getChildNodes().item(j).getChildNodes().getLength() == 1) {
                          value=returnvalue.getChildNodes().item(0).getChildNodes().item(i).getChildNodes().item(j).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                      } else {
                          value =""; 
                      }

                      keyvaluepairs.put  ( key, value );
                      System.out.println("added "+key+" = "+value);
                  }
                  ReturnArray.add(keyvaluepairs);
              } else {
                  System.out.println("No items ");
              }
            }
          } else {
              System.out.println("no return" + returnvalue.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeName());
          }
      } else {
          System.out.println("nothing returned");
      }

      // Close the connection           
      connection.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
  }


}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @hakre how to get rid of this error?

Comment: By using [well-formed XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document).